# Convert SQL Datareader to Dataset in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataset, datareader

I am exporting large set of records from database to Dataset which may be a cause for System.OutofMemory exception. To prevent this, as first step I have decided to use SQL Datareader. My concern is presentation should not be changed and there should be minimal code change in BL, I should write a method in DL which should retrieve data using SQL reader and fill the dataset and return to BL.

Comment: have you thought about using SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)?

Comment: Currently I am using DataAdapter only to fill records to dataset!

Comment: I see, are you trying to get all the data from the table or only records matching a specific criteria?

Comment: Only records matching a specified search criteria

Comment: about how many records are returned then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3721/discussion-between-banupriya-and-dani)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DataTable.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load.aspx) method.

Comment: I am trying to get data using DataReader instead of DataAdapter, because I need to handle large amount of data. After getting using ExecuteReader(), i am loading it to datatable. So whether this is a good approach. ?

Comment: @Harie - I suggest the Load() method. Fill() especially used to populates DataSet (adding one or more tables), creates relations and so on. Have a look at article by Scott Mitchell- http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050405-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Whether you or the Framework fills the DataSet you'll have the OutOfMemoryException.
You have to [return an IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) and change the BL code to handle it.

Alternatively, you could try to set the [DataTable.MinimumCapacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datatable.minimumcapacity.aspx) to avoid memory fragmentation.

Comment: +1 because I agree - how does going via a datareader help reduce memory usage? Presumably though it may be possible to do crazy things with an object that looks like a DataTable but actually has an ienumerabe inside it to return row data. Would be tricky to do but could prevent problems with recoding the BL.